# 404 Not Found react axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios, mern

I am getting this error whenever i am trying to post the data to my mongodb. Here are my axios file,onFinish function and routes files.

index.js:

```
const onFinish = async (values) => {
    try {
      values.seller = user._id;
      values.status = "pending";
      dispatch(SetLoader(true));
      const response = await AddProduct(values);
      dispatch(SetLoader(false));
      if (response.success) {
        message.success(response.message);
        setShowProductForm(false);
      } else {
        throw new Error(response.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(SetLoader(false));
      message.error(error.message);
    }
  };
```

product.js

```
export const AddProduct = async (payload) => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.post(
      "/api/products/add-product",
      payload
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return error.message;
  }
};
```

and productRoute.js

```
router.post("/add-product", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newProduct = new Product(req.body);
    await newProduct.save();
    res.send({
      success: true,
      message: "Product added successfully",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code/confirm that you are mounting the `router` with the correct path: `app.use('/api/products', router)`?

Comment: app.use("/api/products", productsRoute);

Comment: What  `baseURL` did you set for the axios instance?

Comment: "http://localhost:5000/"  this is the baseURL. I actually got it working i didn't put '/' at the end of the proxy mention in my frontend package.json . The proxy mention should be like  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/", the slash(/) at the end was missing. That was causing the error.